# Dash to Panel GNOME extension icons grouped to left side of panel

Tags: gnome, panel, gnome-shell-extension

I have the Dash to Panel GNOME extension installed, and I don't know what happened, but for some reason all the apps and icons are grouped to the left side of the panel and won't move. See the screenshot below:

[image: Dash to Panel icons grouped to the left]

Can someone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: That's the default setting of that extension to make it more Windows like, however, there might be some D2P extension settings, to make it look otherwise. Although, in your case, since the system tray is also at the wrong side, you must dig inside its settings.

Comment: It was working fine for a month or so, but then this just happened. I'll look into my settings

Comment: Try removing and reinstalling it

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled it, but it's still the same

Comment: It might be bug within, you may try it after a few days.

Comment: K, I'll do that

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this out (had been bugging me for a while) so hopefully it will help someone in the future:

1. Right click on an empty space on the Panel bar
2. Click Panel > Panel Preferences...
3. Click "Items" at the top
4. Find the "Separator" which is where you would expect icon to the right to be on the right hand side of the screen. For me it was between "Windows Buttons" and "PulseAudio Plugin"
5. Click on the edit icon (4 bars for me)
6. Tick the "Expand" tickbox.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Extension Manager](https://github.com/mjakeman/extension-manager), you can see Ubuntu AppIndicators below, which determines in which box the running application icons will be placed.

Perhaps you can also combine that with [order-gnome-shell-extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org//extension/2114/order-gnome-shell-extensions/) to be specific about the order within that box. **The problem, however, is that it's extremely buggy!**

Note: If the date/time widget disappears during the process, just disable then enable the main Dash to Panel extension.